# Why does this composition function apply functions in the wrong order when passed as a reference?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, mapping, function-composition

### Problem

The problem is that a composition function sometimes applies its functions in the wrong order but only when it is passed as a reference (e.g., `mapValues(compose(appendB, appendA))(wordNumberMap)`).

Whereas if the composition function is applied directly to a given value, it applies its functions in the correct order (e.g., `mapValues(v => compose(appendB, appendA)(v))(wordNumberMap)`).

[image: composition-direct-vs-ref]

### Questions

1. What causes passing the composition function by reference to apply its functions incorrectly?
2. What (if possible) can be done to maintain the correct order of functions when passing the composition function by reference (e.g., `mapValues(compose(appendB, appendA))`?

### Code

The following code shows all functions working individually and demonstrates how using the composition function directly works whilst passing the composition function by reference fails:

```
// All functions:
const appendA = v => v + 'a';
const appendB = v => v + 'b';
const appendC = v => v + 'c';
const compose = (...functions) => initial => functions.reverse().reduce((result, next) => next(result), initial);
const mapValues = (mapper = v => v) => (obj = {}) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, key) => ({ ...result, [key]: mapper(obj[key], key) }), {});

// `compose` works:
compose(appendC, appendB, appendA)(1); //=> "1abc"

// `mapValues` works:
const wordNumberMap = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };
// `appendA` applied directly:
mapValues(v => appendA(v))(wordNumberMap); //=> {one: "1a", two: "2a", three: "3a", four: "4a", five: "5a"}
// `appendA` applied by reference:
mapValues(appendA)(wordNumberMap); //=> {one: "1a", two: "2a", three: "3a", four: "4a", five: "5a"}

// Applying `compose` directly applies the functions in the correct order:
mapValues(v => compose(appendC, appendB, appendA)(v))(wordNumberMap) //=> {one: "1abc", two: "2abc", three: "3abc", four: "4abc", five: "5abc"}

// Passing `compose` by reference applies the functions in the incorrect order:
mapValues(compose(appendC, appendB, appendA))(wordNumberMap); //=> {one: "1abc", two: "2cba", three: "3abc", four: "4cba", five: "5abc"}
// The returned object shows that every other entry in the returned object has a value where the append functions have been applied incorrectly in reverse order - why does this happen?
```

Comment: `functions` gets `.reverse()`-d and `.reverse()`-d.

Comment: I see but the functions are entered in reverse, furthermore, why are the even values not reversed whilst the odd values are reversed (e.g., `one: "1abc"` isn't reversed but `"two: "2cba"` is reversed)

Comment: actually, I see what you mean but thought that each `compose` is getting a new array of `functions` so `.reverse` wouldn't be re-applied

Comment: `[appendC, appendB, appendA].reverse()` changes the array to `[appendA, appendB, appendC]`. Every second `reverse` will be the opposite.

Comment: *calling* `compose()` makes the array, so one call = one array.

Comment: that makes sense but why does passing directly work? i.e., `mapValues(v => compose(appendC, appendB, appendA)(v))(wordNumberMap)`

Comment: can you explain why there's a difference in `compose`'s behaviour when passing directly (`mapValues(v => compose(appendC, appendB, appendA)(v))(wordNumberMap);`) and when passing by reference (`mapValues(compose(appendC, appendB, appendA))(wordNumberMap);`)?

Comment: isn't `compose` called in both cases?

Comment: If you *call* compose three times you get `[f, g, h]` -> `h, g, f]` -> `[f, g, h]` executed. If you do `v => compose(appendC, appendB, appendA)(v)` then you only get `[f, g, h]` since you're not `.reverse()`-ing the same array twice.

Comment: I see, so `mapValues(compose(...))` passes a reference to `compose` which uses the _same_ `function` array (hence `reverse` can be re-applied to cause the incorrect behaviour), whilst `mapValues(v => compose(...))` creates a new `compose` with a _new_ array, is this correct? If so, can you summarise this in an answer and I'll accept it to help others facing a similar problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code you create a closure, which means your `...functions` array is shared between calls

```
const compose = (...functions) => initial => ...
```

The root of the problem is that [the reverse() method reverses an array **in place**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), so if you call the return value of `compose(appendC, appendB, appendA)` multiple times (which is what you do when you "*pass compose by reference"*), you will reverse the same array time and time again.

---

This effect is mitigated when you "*Apply compose directly*" because you create a brand new composed function at each iteration:

```
mapValues(v => compose(appendC, appendB, appendA)(v))
```

so the fact that you mutate the `...functions` inside `compose` is not a problem because the return value is short lived.

---

As a rule: never mutate your inputs in functional programming. It's a side-effect. you can mutate local variables all you like if it fits your style, but not your inputs.

Especially when you curry (the closure pattern `a => b => ...`) because you share the first input across calls.

---

You can implement `compose` like so:

```
const composition = (f, g) => x => g(f(x));
const id = x => x;
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduceRight(composition, id);
```

Or if you prefer

```
const apply = (x, f) => f(x);
const compose = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight(apply, x);
```

Or if you need to apply multiple arguments to the entry point

```
const apply = (x, f) => f(x);
const compose = (...fns) => (...xs) => {
  const last = fns[fns.length -1];
  const init = fns.slice(0, -1)
  return init.reduceRight(apply, last(...xs))
};
```

Note that in the first version the iteration takes place when you call `compose`, whereas in the other two it occurs when you apply the returned function with arguments.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it summarizes the issue & provides an alternative. "never mutate your inputs in functional programming" is sound advice & "you share the first input across calls" was key to the issue. I also found another (likely less performant) alternative to `.reduceRight` involving tweaking the original code to prevent mutation `const compose = (...functions) => initial => [...functions].reverse().reduce((result, next) => next(result), initial);`, thanks again :)

Comment: You made me realise I had made the second implementation more complex than it could have been. It is meant to accept multiple arguments. I edited my answer to reflect that. I like the very first implementation because it makes it visible that function composition is a monoid (if the types are the same) : there is a neutral element `id` and a closed, associative, binary operation `composition`.